# Newbie Adhesive Question

Tags: adhesives

Our GPS trackers on our dogs were broken over the weekend and upon analysis I found some pins that were removed from the chip.  It appears that there was some type of adhesive glue holding them onto place, but don't know what kind/type to purchase to attempt to repair.  I'm not even sure if these are the correct terminologies, so looking this up is a bit difficult.  Does anyone have any pointers as to what the adhesive was holding these onto place?  They weren't soldered.  It was like it was glue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it was adhesive? And not a surface mount component whose solder was sheared off? Because those look like metal contacts which would not be glued. That "adhesive" might be protective conformal coating which you should see it covering the entire board if it is...a thin shiny laquer which might be hard or might be gummy. It could also be mechanical adhesive to support the pins after they were soldered to the board since surface mount joints are not very strong.

Comment: There is no glue that can hold headers like that. It was either sheared off when they broke or *incorrectly* soldered

Comment: No, not sure it was adhesive.  It could possibly be a miniscule amount of solder - would that be likely?  I guess I need a very fine soldering iron to get that small amount?

Comment: I have seen silver-filled epoxy used for things like this.  Probably very pricey.

Comment: @efru. Nah, I actually recommend the largest soldering iron you can get in there. I prefer an iron about twice the size of my workpiece if I can fit it in. Chisel tip or hoof tip. No conical. They suck

Comment: I guess you can count solder as a kind of hot-melt adhesive. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solder broke. That is likely to happen if there's mechanical stress on the solder alone … as in this case.

While you could try to repair that yourself with a hot air pistol, I recommend to take that piece to a repair cafe and let someone do it who does this all the time. The difference between repaired and gone forever is about 10 seconds, or 10 millimeters.

I also think this design is pretty shitty, as there is always mechanical stress on a charging connector. This connector wasn't intended for that use but for contacting a battery instead. Proper connectors for mechanical stress have additional tabs at least, if not bolt holes.

These are just pogopins on a spacer, it seems. They are intended for lab use …

Comment: Thank you sir.  This was a dog's GPS collar so I'm surprised with how little solder they put on it.  I couldn't even see any.

Comment: It's only a paste put on the board. Then the components are sticked in to the paste and the whole board is baked inside a reflow oven. The tin inside the paste melts and solders the component to the pad.